# speicify custom url and for angular-breadcrumb

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ncybreadcrumb

I am using [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) in my current project.

I want to change some URLs in breadcrumb and set custom link. like this:

```
.state('app.products', {
   url: '/product/productId=:id',
      templateUrl: './app/templates/products/product.html',
      controller: 'productCtrl'

   ncyBreadcrumb: {label: '{{breadcrumbTitle}}', customLink: "{{URL}}"}
})
```

I am using custom template for breadcrumbs, but didnt work what I want!

```
ul.breadcrumb

   li(ng-repeat='step in steps | limitTo:(steps.length-1)')
      a(href='{{step.customLink}}', ng-bind-html='step.ncyBreadcrumbLabel')

   li.active(ng-repeat='step in steps | limitTo:-1')
      span(ng-bind-html='step.ncyBreadcrumbLabel')
```

How can I set `$scope.URL` in my Controller?